# Class not found after extending another class

Tags: php, class, extends, classnotfound

I have a file called Login.php which gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Login' not found
```

The file structure is as follows:

```
require_once('includes/Config.php');
require_once('includes/Initialize.php');
require_once('includes/Database.php');
require_once('includes/Cookie.php');

$database = new Database();
$login = new Login($database);

?>

<!-- Start of HTML SECTION COMES HERE -->

<form action="Login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Username" />
    <input type="text" name="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<!-- End of HTML SECTION COMES HERE -->

<?php
require_once('includes/Config.php');

class Login extends Config{

function __construct(){
    //Construct function handles the forms
}
```

Now, as known, when you use a class, function, variable or any other name reference in a programming language, you must first DECLARE IT.
The thing is, the code, as it is, without the extension:

```
class Login{

function __construct(){
    //Construct function handles the forms
}
```

**Works perfectly.**

**Just after adding the extension,** as mentioned above, the problem occurs.
I have a few other classes using the same method, AND extending the Config class, without returning any error.

Any ideas what happens here differently?

By the way, do you think that structure is preferred?

The issue if being mentioned in many threads, and on stackoverflow too, but as I saw until now, some saying it's some sort of a bug, but no real solution is being showed up, and it's been said about much earlier versions oh PHP.

Comment: After adding just the `extends Config` or the `require` line too? Either way, please also provide that `Config` code.

Comment: You're invoking `$login = new Login($database);` and **after** that, you have `class Login...` - doesn't that strike you as.. problematic?

Comment: As I mentioned, the code worked until now, WITH the class Login after the invoke. Only after adding the "extends Config", the problem occurred.

Comment: You have two includes for includes/Config.php. This is not neccessary. But show us this file, please. My guess would be, that it cannot create the class Login, because there is a problem with the class Config, which it extends.

By the way. It seems strange to inherit Login from Config.

Answer (score 0):

Switched the order inside the file, to:

1. Declaring the class.
2. Invoking it before ?>, and after the class end.
3. Then the HTML Code comes.

Works now.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP scripts execution happens in two steps: first the file is compiled to a binary format then this binary format is interpreted, one statement at a time.

The compilation step verifies that the program is conform with the lexical and syntax rules of the language. However, it checks and compiles only the main file you pass to it. The included files are processed during the execution step. On the compilation step they are not checked in any way (not even that they exist.)

Let's see how your program is executed. First, the syntax of the code is verified and it is compiled to the binary format. The `Login` class is defined in the file but it extends the `Config` class which is not defined here. It is probably defined in the `includes/Config.php` file but that file is not compiled during the compilation step but at the runtime. This makes the definition of the `Login` class unavailable after the compilation step and this is why the interpreter cannot found it. It will be completed during the execution step, after the interpreter reads and executes the definition of the `Config` class.

If you move the usage of the `Login` class after its declaration, when the interpreter reaches the statement `require 'includes/Config.php';` during the runtime, it reads and compiles the file and this way it learns about the class `Config`. When it reaches the declaration of class `Login` it knows how the class `Config` looks like and it can build the definition of class `Login` too. Only after that the class `Login` is available for use.